# docker pull microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb

I've been trying to run

```
docker pull microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator
```

using docker version `18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513)` community edition.

I get

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator
3889bb8d808b: Downloading [==================================================>]  2.933GB/2.933GB
133e38d368dd: Download complete
f94d7004abd2: Download complete
dfd0eefd0cd7: Download complete
7bd4b451efc4: Download complete
b26f8905bde3: Download complete
fc00789d734e: Download complete
218e1ddd98a2: Download complete
ea87ca45a7dc: Download complete
e38453bd2207: Download complete
f61faa8e36ca: Download complete
435c4587562d: Download complete
f96d01133f4f: Download complete
8f622df83d07: Download complete
48e4072766b9: Download complete
01a4cf9780ff: Download complete
3b5c14df7144: Download complete
f5b01cb829ee: Download complete
local error: tls: bad record MAC
```

I know there was a issue with this quite a few months ago, but that was in previous versions (that was apparently fixed)

Comment: I pulled it again and it seemed to work.... this is slightly dodgy

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm glad you were able to pull the docker image when you retried today. I attempted to reproduce the issue with `18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513)` on one of my test machines and didn't see the problem.

I've been working with the docker image quite a bit recently. More than one group at Microsoft (inside and outside Cosmos DB) are going to be using it in their CI systems. Hence, the pull process must be air tight; not dodgy.

If you see this issue again, please send e-mail to [Ask Azure Cosmos DB](http://askcosmosdb@microsoft.com) and I will pick it up.

Thanks for using the Emulator on docker.

Comment: I was working through the steps. docker complains when doing the volume mount, I had to use the full path, `%LOCALAPPDATA%` doesn't work in docker.

Comment: It sounds like we may have a documentation issue. Can you point me to the steps you're referring to?

Comment: See https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-documentdb-emulator/ section Running inside Docker